# Use of colon to elaborate upon clause

Tags: punctuation, colons

I'm wondering if sentence structures such as the following are a valid use of the colon:

> I don't understand your second point: Is it not said that the sky is blue?

As you can see, I'm using the colon to elaborate upon the previous clause "*I don't understand your second point*".

If this isn't a valid use of the colon, then what would be considered a valid punctuation mark in this type of situation? Or is it the case that it is a valid use of the colon, but that there are better punctuation marks for this type of situation?

I would greatly appreciate it if people would please take the time to clarify this.

Comment: Maybe a book says a colon can introduce an elaboration, but the second part here does not introduce the other party's second point. It's your comment on that. I'd give you a pass if you chose the colon here deliberately. But doesn't a period -- or an em dash -- do the job? Maybe this is the rare time to use a ... semicolon.

Comment: @YosefBaskin The second clause is elaborating on the first clause; that is, it elaborates as to the reason *why* I don't understand their second point.

Comment: Although the use of the colon is becoming much rarer, one can still find recommendations from reasonable sources saying nothing more than 'A colon is used to introduce something that follows on reasonably from some previous context'. To introduce something to expand, explain, emphasise, ask for clarification .... Here, a follow-up question expanding on 'I don't understand your second point' is reasonable (if the second point made it so!), and the grammar (which is pretty flexible after a colon) is fine (an interrogative sentence), so the colon is acceptable. Again, if old-fashioned.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth thanks for the clarification. What would be more suitable punctuation?

Comment: Here, two sentences would be fine.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth eh, but that makes the two clauses seem too independent, no? Isn’t there any punctuation more appropriate?

Comment: I'd be happy with two sentences, but take your point; a dash (usually em in the US but en in the UK) can usually be a modern replacement for a colon. The semicolon and the ellipsis are also reasonable choices here.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I don’t understand your second point — is it not said that the sky is blue? Is that what you’re referring to?

Comment: While agreeing with @EdwinAshworth, won't it be another option that they are linked with a semicolon, like "I don't understand your second point; is it not said that the sky is blue?"?

Comment: @RamPillai yes, I think that is also valid, since the second clause is dependent on the first.